# what is the full path to rails on Mac OSX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

what is the full path to rails on a Mac?

`which rails` won't help me at the moment because I don't have rails properly installed and possibly don't have the file at all. Either that or it's not in my path.

But it'd help to know the location where the file should be.

(I am not using any ruby version control manager e.g. not using rvm, if that even makes a difference)

Comment: Maybe try using the 'find' command

Comment: @BaileyKocin Trying that now, `find rails . -name 'rails'` though it's possible it's not on my system. Do you not have osx and rails? looks like every project has a rails command.. makes me wonder what rails command was being used or would be used when i'm not in a project (though currently I don't have rails installed right so can't test)

Comment: Do you use gem? You can type gem env to find rubys executable? As for the find command try 'find . - executable ' then grep that maybe?

Comment: @BaileyKocin I can't make head or tail of your find command. Can you be specific. You say `find . - executable`. Well, if I do `find . - rails` (which looks absolutely ridiculous ) then it says `find: -: unknown primary or operator`.  And I can try gem env, but why are you telling me how to find the ruby executable. I am not looking for the ruby executable, I'm looking for rails.

Comment: Oh sorry! Try '-executable' was just a flag. So this works 'find . -type f -executable -print' . Then grep that output for rails or ruby things.

Comment: gem env shows me a gems directory, and I can go to `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rails-5.2.2.1$` and do ls and I see a readme.  I don't see a rails file

Comment: does it show a ruby executable variable?

Comment: `/$ find . -type f -executable -print ` says `find: -executable: unknown primary or operator`. (even before I do any grep), So I think your find command is wrong again?

Comment: @BaileyKocin why should I be looking for a ruby executable variable? I can see that from doing `which ruby` it's there. `/usr/local/bin/ruby`

Comment: Okay. What are you actually looking for. You are asking where rails is installed? No? You said which rails didnt help? Maybe I'm just confused....

Comment: @BaileyKocin Rails yes, I'm asking about rails, so why are you asking me to look for ruby?

Comment: You are totally right. You say you didn't properly install rails but how did you put it on your system exactly? Homebrew?

Comment: @BaileyKocin originally, I don't know, and it was installed properly. Then I did some tests with reverting to a very early version of rails and I can't get it back to 5.2.2.1 . I went back to 0.8.0 which uses some kind of rake command rather than rails, and just broke rails

Comment: @BaileyKocin you did give me an idea though, I will do brew install rails and see how that goes.

Comment: @BaileyKocin there is no brew install of rails, it seems everything you are saying is completely wrong.  rails would've been installed with gem install rails

Comment: You dont brew install rails. I got ruby and rails mixed up. You use gem for rails i think. Look through gem.

Comment: @BaileyKocin furthermore, that directory I showed SHOULD just have a readme, so that was actually fine

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rails installed to a sufficient enough degree to do `which rails` and I see it's here

```
$ which rails
/usr/bin/rails
```